# How to show tooltip with qtip

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to show a tooltip when i hover an item but it dosnt worked heres the code :

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", '.vis-item', function ($e) {
      // $(this).tooltip('enable').tooltip('open');
      $(this).qtip({
         // Simply use an HTML img tag within the HTML string
         content: 'i am a qtip'
      });
      //$(this).css('background-color', 'red');
      console.log("TEST");
 });
```

P.S:
the console.log it appears in the console that means the event is good but the tooltip dosnt appear.

Comment: Please read [the documentation](http://qtip2.com/guides). You're adding the qtip declaration on "mouseenter"; qtip provides its own event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably need something like this:

```
$('.vis-item').qtip({
    content: 'i am a qtip'
});
```

Comment: @abdellatifzoumhane Is your project publicly available? If not - could you reproduce your issue using jsfiddle?

Comment: its a private project..actually .vis-item is class generated by javascript..when i replaced by another id it works

Comment: I can't help you without seeing your code and/or demo. Could you reproduce your issue using jsfiddle?